# What is the difference between the 1969 and 1975 editions of "The Cosmic Eye" by Mack Reynolds?

Tags: the-cosmic-eye

I'm collecting Mack Reynold's books.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mack_Reynolds#Novels) there are two editions of "The Cosmic Eye", published 1969 and 1975.  I already have the 1969 edition; is the 1975 edition significantly different, or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISFDB is generally better than Wikipedia for revised editions and similar bibliographic information. It looks like each *Cosmic Eye* is the same book inside:

- The [ISFDB listing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?535125) says nothing about revisions from the earlier printing to the later one.
- The [1969](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?268241) and [1975](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?285219) editions have the same page count.

To be certain, you would have to check the actual books.